# How to resolve this Visual Studio issue with looking for .props file in wrong location?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, project, vsprops

I have a project that I'm not even able to open because of an error:

```
proj_path.vcxproj : error  : The imported project "some_other_path\p.props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
```

I have 
`p.props` file in project directory, but Visual Studio 2010 keeps loking for it in some other folder that not even exist on my PC. Where to fix this paths?

Comment: HI, have you found any fix?  Having same issue for one project in vs 2015